# NTP Server - +Hour

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

How can we implement NTP server with ability to distribute its time with +X hours or -X hours and without changing TZ on our operating systems. NTS has this ability but it's available for Windows.

**Custom time zone and offset**
Using this unique feature, customize the source time (for example, received from an NIST NTP Server) and distribute it to the time clients. Keep your time synchronized with UTC or convert it to the local time, add or deduct any number seconds/minutes/hours from the source time to have your own time offset.
https://nts.softros.com/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. NTP is UTC and unaware of time zones. Attempting to hack an offset into your time sources will break NTP. And possibly break applications with a requirement for time sync, like Kerberos.

Time zone is like any other host configuration. Set a default in your base operating system image. Set it differently per group of hosts if needed. Possibly allow users to change it.

---

Softros Network Time Server has an unfortunate acronym collision with Network Time Security for NTP.  The former is proprietary, the latter a [proposed standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8915) with implementations recently arriving in Linux distros, namely [Fedora with chrony](https://fedoramagazine.org/secure-ntp-with-nts/).